# jFeed not parsing images inside RSS feed

Tags: jquery

Suggestions on how to fix this?

It's imperative that I use javascript, sadly, or I would have been using SimplePie eons ago.

Comment: @Judson can you post relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

jFeed does not support images as it isn't a standard RSS element (optional sub-element in RSS 2.0).

You'll need to extend jFeed to your requirements as was suggested to me in this question: [Does JFeed support RSS images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544543/does-jfeed-support-rss-images)

My RSS feed is not standard and simply has a 'thumbnail' root property so my code probably won't be helpful to you.