# Does JFeed support RSS images?

Tags: jquery, rss, jfeed

I've had a look at JFeed's readme and it doesn't mention anyway to get to an RSS item's image:

## JFeedItem properties

```
* item.title
* item.link
* item.description
* item.updated
* item.id
```

Does anyone know a way to parse these images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer "**No**".

There is no default [jFeed](http://www.hovinne.com/blog/index.php/2007/07/15/132-jfeed-jquery-rss-atom-feed-parser-plugin) support for "image" access for RSS (or "icon"/"logo" access for ATOM).

That said you could always extend the library to support feed images.  For example in **jrss.js** you could add:

```
var image = jQuery('image', xml).eq(0);

this.image = new Object();
this.image.url = jQuery(image).find('url:first').text();
this.image.title = jQuery(image).find('title:first').text();
this.image.link = jQuery(image).find('link:first').text();
```

From an RSS feed you would then be able to access:

```
feed.image.url
```

But this only facilitates accessing the graphic for the entire feed and not individual items.

To support individual item images you would need to extend jFeed to allow it to support attributes in some way.

For example to support RSS 2.0 enclosures you could fold the attributes into elements, so you would be able to access something like:

```
item.enclosure.url
```

In **jrss.js** you could add something like:

```
jQuery('item', xml).each( function() {

    var item = new JFeedItem();

    item.title = jQuery(this).find('title').eq(0).text();
    item.link = jQuery(this).find('link').eq(0).text();
    item.description = jQuery(this).find('description').eq(0).text();
    item.updated = jQuery(this).find('pubDate').eq(0).text();
    item.id = jQuery(this).find('guid').eq(0).text();

    item.enclosure = new Object();

    var enc = jQuery(this).find('enclosure');

    item.enclosure.url = jQuery(enc).attr('url');
    item.enclosure.length = jQuery(enc).attr('length');
    item.enclosure.type = jQuery(enc).attr('type');

    feed.items.push(item);
});
```

I'm tired and making this up as I go along, can you tell? ;)

Comment: That all makes sense - I've had a crack at it but can't seem to access the item's thumbnail element.
RSS snippet:
<item> <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://url/something.jpg"></media:thumbnail></item>
jfeeditem.js:
function JFeedItem() {};

JFeedItem.prototype = {

    title: '',
    link: '',
    description: '',
    updated: '',
    id: '',
    thumbnailurl: ''
};
jrss.js:
...
item.id = jQuery(this).find('guid').eq(0).text();
   item.thumbnailurl = jQuery(this).find('media:thumbnail').attr('url');

the thumbnail property remains undefined and I can't seem to match it.

Comment: Okay your problem looks to be namespace related.  Try one of the solutions suggested here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128580/jquery-find-problem

Comment: super easy to implement, by the way - I'm sort of used to not diving too deep into plugin customization, so it's nice to see that this one is straight-forward enough to quickly add a few bits and pieces.